# ACF Image not appearing

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Im setting up a custom field on the woocommerce product page to allow featured content to be added, it needs to upload an image and single line of text, unless there is a better way i have it currently set to load an image as 1 field and the second field is text [Product fields img](http://prntscr.com/cnoimv) and its appearing on the front end like this [img of frontend](http://prntscr.com/cnok2y) is there an extra step needed to make an image get displayed instead of the path?

Theres no code that i have typed, i have acf installed in wordpress, and a pagebuilder which you choose the field and put it into, its using visual composer. [visual composer - page editing](http://prntscr.com/cnslhi)

either something is wrong with the plugin or i have set it up incorrectly in acf, although i dont think its overly complex in acf.

Comment: Can you share your code? We need to see what you're currently trying to do in order spot something that might need changed.

Comment: Sounds like it's missing from your template.